# rsync a list of paths

Tags: rsync

I like to sync changes of a subset of paths/files from two locations. I have the paths of all changes, like some version management tool would list, but no info what happened to them. Sounds simple, but seems almost impossible.. here are the caveats:

Using several source arguments and pinning them with `/./` like

```
rsync -a --delete /some/path/./file1 /some/path/./subfolder/file2 host:/some/path
```

This works except for moved or deleted files, that do not exist in the source side anymore. Those are complaint by rsync and not deleted on the target side.

So I tried using filters instead multiple sources, like `--include=/subfolder/file1 --exclude=*`. However, as the recursion is stopped if a dir is ommitted, it is stop right at top level, and this do not sync any file.

So I added `--include=*/` before the exclude statement, to enable the recursion again. Then any folder not on my list will be synched itself, eg. its metadata is synched. Also with `-v` I end up with a messy output of all folders everywhere.

So I added `-m` as is suggested by some people, that prunes out the 'empty' directorys (which are not really empty, but rendered so by the excludes). However, this does interact with `--delete`, as all directories are now listed for deletion. It seems that in contrast to the other filters, `-m` also put the matching empty dirs to the delete list.

Now I'm running out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem. Normally `--files-from=F`, where F contains the list of paths to update, is fine, *unless* some of the paths in F are to be deleted, in which case it complains it can't stat the source file.

So, I constructed an include-from file. Assume you have paths a/b/c and p/q/r to mirror, write a file "filter" containing:

```
+ a
+ a/b
+ a/b/c
+ a/b/c/**
+ p
+ p/q
+ p/q/r
+ p/q/r/**
- *
```

Then use the command

```
rsync [-v] -r --delete --include-from=filter source/ target
```